# Howto run Nearest Neighbour Search with Lucene HnswGraph

Tags: lucene

I would like to use Lucene to run a nearest neighbour search. I'm using Lucene 9.0.0 on JVM 11. I did not find much documentation and mainly tried to piece things together using the existing [tests](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/54ebf3c73b72bafc414f834a15b8a3e81fd75ad8/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene/util/hnsw/TestHnswGraph.java).

I wrote a small test which prepares a `HnswGraph` but so far the search does not yield the expected result. I setup a set of random vectors and add a final vector (0.99f,0.01f) which is very close to my search target.
The search unfortunately never returns the expected value. I'm not sure where my error is. I assume it may be related with the insert and document id order.

Maybe someone who is more familar with lucene might be able to provide some feedback. Is my approach correct? I'm using Documents only for persistence.

```java
HnswGraphBuilder builder = new HnswGraphBuilder(vectors, similarityFunction, maxConn, beamWidth, seed);
HnswGraph hnsw = builder.build(vectors);

// Run a search
NeighborQueue nn = HnswGraph.search(
    new float[] { 1, 0 },
    10,
    10,
    vectors.randomAccess(), // ? Why do I need to specify the graph values again?
    similarityFunction, // ? Why can I specify a different similarityFunction for search. Should that not be the same that was used for graph creation?
    hnsw,
    null,
    new SplittableRandom(RandomUtils.nextLong()));
```

The whole test source can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/Jotschi/cea21a72412bcba80c46b967e9c52b0f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a top search hit for people like me looking for lucene hnsw examples (there just aren't many out there), here's what this looks like as of Lucene 9.6, without bringing in higher-level Lucene classes:

```
    // Create a random vector universe
    var vectorDimensions = 1500;
    var universeSize = 2_000;
    var universe = new ArrayList<float[]>(universeSize);
    for (var i = 0; i < universeSize; i++) {
        universe.add(randomVector(vectorDimensions));
    }

    // construct a HNSW graph of the universe
    System.out.println("Constructing HNSW graph...");
    var ravv = new ListRandomAccessVectorValues(universe, vectorDimensions);
    var builder = HnswGraphBuilder.create(ravv, VectorEncoding.FLOAT32, similarityFunction, 16, 100, random.nextInt());
    var hnsw = builder.build(ravv.copy());

    // search for the nearest neighbors of a random vector
    var queryVector = randomVector(vectorDimensions);
    System.out.println("Searching for top 10 neighbors of a random vector");
    var nn = HnswGraphSearcher.search(queryVector, 10, ravv.copy(), VectorEncoding.FLOAT32, similarityFunction, hnsw, null, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (var i : nn.nodes()) {
        var neighbor = universe.get(i);
        var similarity = similarityFunction.compare(queryVector, neighbor);
        System.out.printf("  ordinal %d (similarity: %s)%n", i, similarity);
    }
```

The implementation of ListRandomAccessVectorValues is straightforward and can be found here: https://github.com/jbellis/hnswdemo

As you note, the API is a bit wonky, and while you can specify different encodings or similarities to the search than from the builder, you will obviously get nonsense results.

The reason you have to pass the vector values in to the search function is that for efficiency, the index itself does not store a copy of the vectors themselves, but only an int offset into the values provider.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working.

Instead of using the `HnswGraph` API directly I now use `LeafReader#searchNearestVectors`. While debugging I noticed that the `Lucene90HnswVectorsWriter` for example invokes extra steps using the `HnswGraph` API. I assume this is done to create a correlation between inserted vectors and document Ids. The nodeIds I retrieved using a `HnswGraph#search` never matched up with the matched up with the vector Ids. I don't know whether extra steps are needed to setup the graph or whether the correlation needs to be created afterwards somehow.

The good news is that the `LeafReader#searchNearestVectors` method works. I have updated the example which now also makes use of the Lucene documents.

```java
@Test
public void testWriteAndQueryIndex() throws IOException {
    // Persist and read the data
    try (MMapDirectory dir = new MMapDirectory(indexPath)) {
        // Write index
        int indexedDoc = writeIndex(dir, vectors);
        // Read index
        readAndQuery(dir, vectors, indexedDoc);
    }
}
```

Vector 7 with [0.97|0.02] is very close to the search query target [0.98|0.01].

```
Test vectors:
0 => [0.13|0.37]
1 => [0.99|0.49]
2 => [0.98|0.57]
3 => [0.23|0.64]
4 => [0.72|0.92]
5 => [0.08|0.74]
6 => [0.50|0.27]
7 => [0.97|0.02]
8 => [0.90|0.21]
9 => [0.89|0.09]
10 => [0.11|0.95]

Doc Based Search:
Searching for NN of [0.98 | 0.01]
TotalHits: 11
7 => [0.97|0.02]
9 => [0.89|0.09]
```

Full example:
https://gist.github.com/Jotschi/d8a91758c84203d172f818c8be4964e4

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to use the KnnVectorQuery.

```java
try (IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir)) {
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    System.out.println("Query: [" + String.format("%.2f", queryVector[0]) + ", " + String.format("%.2f", queryVector[1]) + "]");
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(new KnnVectorQuery("field", queryVector, 3), 10);
    System.out.println("Hits: " + results.totalHits);
    for (ScoreDoc sdoc : results.scoreDocs) {
        Document doc = reader.document(sdoc.doc);
        StoredField idField = (StoredField) doc.getField("id");
        System.out.println("Found: " + idField.numericValue() + " = " + String.format("%.1f", sdoc.score));
    }
}
```

Full example:
https://gist.github.com/Jotschi/7d599dff331d75a3bdd02e62f65abfba